# Getting Internal server error for partcular request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting Internal server error in jmeter for particular request but same url its working fine in browser,even i handled the cookie in the script and checked web traffic in fiddler and header manager everything is correct but still its showing internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to configure some HTTP header in your request to make it work. Your browser is inserting them as default, but for JMeter you need to do it manually.

Using a recording tool might help on the specifics, but even though you will need some changes on your test script.

I recommend BlazeMeter Chrome Plugin, it will insert any necessary HTTP headers for you based on the browser of choice.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi

Your site might require Cookies, therefore you need to use a Cookie Manager for that. In order to Test the requests, use the Listeners "Response Assert" or "Save Responses to a File" to check if the response was sent properly.